# How to access ListItem from code behind when using DataTemplate - ListBox

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, listitem

I have listbox which binds data to DataTable and now I need to access specific List Item, let's say first 5th one, from source behind code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=AllMainCategoriesTable}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" x:Name="lbMainCategories">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=main_category_name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="grpMainCategory" x:Name="rdbEnableDisable" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Width="30" Background="Transparent" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my foreach loop to access each listitem but I am enable to cast liSelectedMainCategory to ListItem...What am I doing wrong????

```
foreach (ListItem liSelectedMainCategory in lbMainCategores.Items)
                { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Items property which is a collection of containers.  Elements in that collection would not cast the way you want.  Consider using something like this fragment...

```
    ICollectionView icv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox1.Items);
    foreach (var v in icv)
    {
        var lbi = v as ListBoxItem;
        if (lbi != null)
        {
            var s = lbi.Content; // what you are after is here...
        }
    }
```

Comment: lbi is always null :(  How to get access Radio button in ListBox DataTemplate?

Comment: v is a DataRowView and lbi is null after the assignment. It never passes IF statement. Well, I did my task by adding Load Event on radio button and check there if this is the desired radio button, then do work. But really thanks for your help.